# Подскажите, как расставить знаки препинания?

Tags: пунктуация

Когда человек обманывает других это театр, когда себя самого клиника.

Answer (score 3):

Я бы в обеих частях сложного предложения поставила тире. *Когда человек обманывает других -  это театр, когда себя самого - клиника.* Здесь тот интересный случай, когда на месте подлежащего стоит целое предложение. Сравните: *Обман других - театр, обман самого себя - клиника.*